# Tar & save the output of a command

Tags: linux, tar, gzip, cat

I want to tar the output of a command, say `cat hello.world`, to a compressed tar file.

I don’t want to save a temporary file and later tar it manually.

How can I do this?

Comment: `tar` pretty much requires real files, in order to give meaningful names in the archive.  Your best bet is probably to use the [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) module of Python.

Answer (score 1):

`tar` files store not just the contents of files but also the file names, the file permissions, and more.  None of that applies to "the output of a command."

From your description, it sounds like you just need `gzip`.  For example:

```
command | gzip >output.gz
```

This captures the output of `command`, compresses it, and saves it to file `output.gz`.

Comment: +1 `tar` is a tool to *join multiple files into one,* the compression options are just a convenience to use it *together with* `gzip` and the like.